# Handling GridItems click

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml, expression-blend

Starting with a Grouped Items Page template, I want to be able to perform tasks on the grid items when they are clicked. Namely, I want to change the background image, and add/remove the underlying object to a list of selected items.

Here's my DataTemplate:

```
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="2" Margin="0,0,20,20">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="390" Height="190">
                    <Grid.Background>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/unselected.png" Stretch="None"/>
                    </Grid.Background>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <Image VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="None" Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
                        <StackPanel MaxWidth="270">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Summary}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Brand}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Detail}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
```

OnTap, I want to togle the `ImageSource` value of the `Grid.Background` from *unselected.png* to *selected.png*. This I believe I can do using VisualStates and Storyboards, but I've been unable to get this to work in the past (I'll spare you the chaos of my attempts in xaml).

Needless to say, I've tried following the steps detailed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd185499%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) using Blend, but the Grid.Background property doesn't seems to be state specific. If I try changing the background brush in the Pressed or Selected states, it also changes for the Normal state.

Since I want to grab the data context of the selected item and add/remove it from a list, should I just be handling all this together in an `OnTap` event handler? I would prefer to keep these concerns separated, but I'll do what I need to...

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One clean way to do this would be engage the selection method (Tap) in such a way that it only opperates on its items, and the items themselves have properties which Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface

Your View Model would have a collection of your custom objects that have properties that can notify the ui

```
public class MyObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private string _summary;
   public string summary 
   {
          get {return _summary}
          set
          {
               _summary = value;
               OnPropertyChanged()
          }
   }


   //Other Properties: brand || detail

   private ImageSource _backgroundImage;
   public ImageSource backgroundImage 
   {
          get {return _backgroundImage}
          set
          {
               _backgroundImage = value;
               OnPropertyChanged()
          }
   }

   private bool _IsSelected;
   public bool IsSelected
   {
          get {return _IsSelected;}
          set
          {
               _IsSelected = value;
               OnPropertyChanged()
          }
   }

}
```

Then although your code behind can be used to change the value of IsSelected, or Background image ... if you choose to go with IsSelected, you can still separate your concerns by not directly setting the resource of the background image in code behind. The Codebehind will only iterate over the items to toggle the IsSelected property, and you can use xaml to define the image that the background should use by creating a custom converter.

```
public class MyCustomControlOrPage.cs : UserControl //Or ApplicationPage
    {

    //.......code


        protected void HandleTap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
        {
             foreach(var item in ((Listbox)sender).ItemsSource)
             {
                 ((MyObject)item.IsSelected = (MyObject)item.Name == (e.NewItems[0] as MyObject).Name? true: false;
             }
        }
    }
```

then the converter

```
public class BackgroundConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ImageSource source = value == true ? new BitmapImage(uriForSelected) : new BitmapImage(uriForunselected);
        return source;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        BitmapImage thisValue = value as BitmapImage;
        return thisValue;
    }
}
```

and FINALLY the XAML where the grid background binds to the IsSelected property and allows the converter to transform the bool to an ImageSource of type BitmapImage:

```
//add xmlns:Converters=clr-namesapce:Yournamespace.UpTo.TheNamespaceBackgroundConverterIsIn" to the page or control definition
<UserControl.Resources>
<Converters:BackgroundConverter x:key="BgSourceConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>
 <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="2" Margin="0,0,20,20">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="390" Height="190">
                    <Grid.Background>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={Binding Source={StaticResource BGSourceConverter}}}" Stretch="None"/>
                    </Grid.Background>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <Image VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="None" Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
                        <StackPanel MaxWidth="270">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Summary}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Brand}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Detail}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
```